# Source latest function file

Tags: r, function

I source in `main.R` a function file:

```
source("struktura/struktura_mp_v1.R")
```

but this whole project is being worked on by a few people, and I would want to load automatically newest version. Is it possible?

Comment: It is better here to create a package here with your code source. People can install/update it from a local repository ( shared one) where you push  the newest version.

Comment: It's good tip, BUT I need to have quick access to previous versions of code and therefore file list in Rstudio project view is good for me. I cant do that in repo.

Comment: Repo here is just a zip of your package source. Users will use this zip to install the package. You can still use R studio ...but to access old version of code you should have a versionning system like git...